# How to post one more parameters to action MVC jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to post three parameters to YeniKayit action. I can post first one. But when I post second one, I get an error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'koyid' of non-nullable type

`YeniKayit` action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YeniKayit(Afet model, HttpPostedFileBase file, int koyid, int mahalleid, int afetturid)
{..}
```

jQuery code:

```
$('select[name=MahalleId]').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")/?mahalleid=' + id)
      });
    $('select[name=Koy]').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")/&koyid=' +id)

    }); 
    $('select[name=afettur]').change(function () {
        var afetid = $(this).val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")/&afetturid=' + afetid)

    });
```

`MahalleId` object:

```
<select name="MahalleId" class="form-control" data-val="true" 
        data-val-required="Mahalle alanı boş bırakılamaz">
</select>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mahalle.MahalleId, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

`Koy` object:

```
<select name="Koy" class="form-control" data-val="true" 
        data-val-required="Köy alanı boş bırakılamaz">
</select>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Koy.KoyId, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

`afettur` object:

```
@Html.DropDownList("afettur", ViewData["Türler"] as SelectList, "-- Tür Seçiniz --", new { style = "width:250px", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: You need `$.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit"), { koyid: someValue, mahalleid: anotherValue, afetturid: anotherValue })` But why do you have a parameter `Afet model` - that makes no sense - and you cannot post a file using `$.post()` so its unclear why you have that parameter as well

Comment: I use model for another process(inserting model's value to database)

Comment: Then unless your model contains properties `koyid`, `mahalleid` and `afetturid` - in which case you can delete all the other parameters - then delete it. Instead, initialize a new instance in the method - `var model = new Afet();`

Comment: You just say someValue,anothervalue..MahalleId,Koy,afettur are select(dropdown).For example If I put $('select[name=Koy]').val() to instead of someValue,does it works?@StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes, But why would you use `$('select[name=Koy]').val()`? It should be `$('#Koy').val()`

Comment: Model doesn't contain them @StephenMuecke

Comment: Does not contain what? And in any case you should not be handling the `.change()` event of each dropdown. You should allow the user to make all selections and have a button and handle its `.click()` event

Comment: I editted post.I added MahalleId,Koy,afettur objects.and I 've try  $.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")', { mahalleid: $('#MahalleId'), koyid: $('#Koy').val(), afetturid: $('#afettur').val() });
then it gives me same error @StephenMuecke

Comment: Another thing,I try that
$('#btnKayit').click(function () {
            $.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")', { mahalleid: $('#MahalleId'), koyid: $('#Koy').val(), afetturid: $('#afettur').val() });
        });
YeniKayit Action didn't work

Comment: thanks for helps,it works fine.I 've changed name of select Koy to KoyId.@StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

Your second query string seems to be wrong.

Give this a try:

```
//change 
$.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")/&koyid=' +id);
//to 
$.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")?koyid=' +id);
```

To troubleshoot, you should implement error function of the .post function as follows:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("YeniKayit")/&koyid=' +id)
  .error(function(responseObject){
   /*the object signature looks like this:
     responseObject= 
     {
       readyState:n
       ,responseText:"server response"
       , status:"http status code"
       , statusText:"the meaning of the status code"
     }
   */
});
```

Here is a good resource: [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

Comment: Infact,it is exactly what I want to do now.Firstly when I change select object's name to KoyId is coloumn name in database,it works fine.I want to  check if user choose any option.Then I've tried your code.Infact I dont understand what I should do